# GeoLocation Configuration

Tags: javascript, html, sql, geolocation, google-visualization

I am working with one of the APM tools. To capture user location a pop_up is coming there.

Now there is the requirement to capture user location without the pop_up appearance. Is there any way we can capture the user location.

Best Regards
Amit Singh Bisht

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the IP Address of the user to get the geo location, But this might not give you the exact location of the user.

And also this needs to be implemented in the backend side, If you are familier with javascript [geolocation API](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp), it can't be accessed without the popup (or otherwise user permission for privacy issues)